# Explain the purpose of this code and give an explanation of how it achieves its purpose

Tags: python

Explain the purpose of this code and give a line-by-line explanation of how it achieves its purpose:

```
def mystery(n):
   a,b = 0,1
   while a < n:
      print(a)
      a,b = b,a + b
```

I understand what the first 4 lines mean:
-defines the code below as mystery(n) where n is a number
-a = 0, b = 1
-as long as a is smaller than n the code below will run
-prints a
I have a problem with the last one. Does it mean a = b and b = a + b? If so , then the output for e.g mystery(10) doesn't match with my theory, so I know its something else.
The output for mystery(10):

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
```

Comment: _Does it mean a = b and b = a + b?_  The answer is: yes

Comment: The next line in your output would be `13`, but that's greater than 10 so the `while` loop will exit before it gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean a = b and b = a + b?

The answer is: yes

These are the Fibonacci numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: I thought, as it is a very common python statement, that it didn't need a response. So I just added a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `a,b = b, a + b`, you can put it several lines like this:

```
a,  b
=   =
b  a+b
```

It is pretty much the same thing as:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

except that `b = a + b` is using the old value of `a`.  That is because the variables aren't defined until the evaluation is complete.  It is the same thing up at the top, except that at the top we don't really need it.  We could say `a = 0` and `b = 1` and not come across any unexpected behavior, but in the case of `a,b = b, a + b`, it wouldn't work right if we defined one variable before we define the other.  The evaluation needs to happen before both definitions or else it won't be right.